How to Handle? vp_page Parameter in WordPress and Resolve Google Search Console Validation Issues?
I am encountering an issue with the? vp_page parameter being generated in the URLs on my WordPress site. Despite adding the Disallow: /*?vp_page= directive to my robots.txt file, the validation in Google Search Console keeps failing, and the pages are still being indexed.
How is the? vp_page parameter being generated?
Why does the robots.txt directive fail to prevent indexing in Google Search Console?
What are the best practices or solutions to handle this parameter effectively and prevent it from being indexed?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
